# Approach for adding posts to a blog type website

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a blog style website using html, CSS and bootstrap. I've recently started learning Javascript.

I want to be able to add/delete posts etc to the blog website. Is Javascript the technology I should be using to do to this? I also thought I could use SQL or something to create a database and somehow have posts be loaded onto the site from the database.

I'm pretty new to all this so I'm not too sure.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is some sort of storing the objects on a server. You can choose from plethora of solutions, naming php and nodejs as most popular ones in web world. On the server you (most of the times) make a connection to the database (sql - mysql, mariadb etc or nosql like mongodb for example) in order to get or set or remove some objects (posts). You can as well store it in files or whatever you want, but database is just created to serve this purpose. Has numerous advantages over another solutions.

And now to the Javascript; you can use it to send the data asynchronously (read about ajax / xhr request) but its completely optional. It's definetely not the core of the proces and it's completely ommitable.

You can build anything from scratch, and such experiments are sometimes beneficial, but most of the times you just want to use some de-facto standard technology that has most of the pitfalls covered and offers you good development experience as well as security benefits (wordpress - cms, symfony frsmework).

Comment: @enito thanks for the detailed answer! I haven't yet learnt server side programming. I'm deciding whether to learn php or nodejs (any recommendation?, I know php is more mature so am tempted by that). The database I don't mind what I use, I am thinking maybe monodb as it's newer, but sql is probably easier? What I'm confused about I guess, is how I connect to the database to then get the post to appear on the site? I'm only doing this as a learning experience, in a production environment, I'd just use wordpress.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with connecting to the database. Surely you can find enough info when you google for "php get data from mysql database" tutorial. Or similar. I thought just now that firebase may  be interesting for you as it allows getting data from its (third party) database with client side Javascript only.

Comment: Yeah I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, ok, take a look. If you think that my answer answered your question then you can mark it as correct answer.